# Problem related to Creation of folder inside the application folder and access its classes in Zend-Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I have following structure in my Zend-Project :

```
-application
      -   PDF
      -   configs
      -   controllers
      -   models
      -   views
      -   Bootstrap.php
-library
-public
-tests
```

I have created a new folder **PDF** inside **application** folder. And I have **write some classes inside** it[PDF].

What I want is to **access this classes** inside the *indexAction() of the IndexController*, but it showing an **error** like :

**"Class 'Application_PDF_FormDocument' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\zendapp\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 13"**

What may be the possible reason?

Please provide some help.....

Thanks In Advance......

Comment: @Fatmuemoo and @ChanibaL   : It is working perfectly for me now, thanks once again......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ChanibaL regarding the naming of your classes. you should be naming it PDF_FormDocumnet.
Next, in application.ini, regerster the namespace:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PDF_"
```

Lastly, in your index.php make sure you are adding it to the include path:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you have a standard autoloader in your application, the class name should be `PDF_FormDocument` (no `Application_` part!) in the file `application/PDF/FormDocument.php`

If this doesn't help by itself try adding

```
    protected function _initAutoload() {
            $autoloader=new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => 'PDF',
                    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PDF'
            ));
```

to `application/Bootstrap.php`